# Showing that $M_n(R[x]) \cong (M_n(R)[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to show that $M_n(R[x]) \cong (M_n(R)[x]$ so I consider the mapping that sends an element $A \in M_n(R[x])$ to the polynomial whose coefficients are matrices in which the entries of those matrices are the coefficients of the polynomials of in $A$. So for example:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
      x^2 & x \\
      3 & 2x+1 
\end{bmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
x^2 + 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
x +
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
3 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Clearly $\phi(A+B) = \phi(A) + \phi(B)$ however it doesn't seem to hold for multiplication. Is this the correct mapping I'm suppose to be considering or is there another that would work better, thanks in advance.

Comment: a ring isomorphism would be a linear map as well between the vector spaces, so take a look at the standard bases in each of the rings. that should help you identify something.

Comment: @justin Why do you think it fails to be multiplicative? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $M_n(R[x])$ is a free $R[x]$ module, and has basis the elementary matrices $E_{ij}$ which are all $0$ except for the $ij$th entry, which is 1. Thus a basis for $M_n(R[x])$ as a free $R$ module is $x^kE_{ij}$. Similarly, a basis for $M_n(R)[x]$ is $E_{ij}x^k$, where I'm using the order of multiplication to distinguish these two rings.

You're trying to show that these $R$-algebras are isomorphic as (presumably) $R$-algebras, so the map should be $R$-linear. Thus such a map is defined by what it does on an $R$-generating set, or in this case since the $R$-algebras are free modules, an $R$-basis. Your map $\phi$ is the map defined by sending $x^kE_{ij}$ to $E_{ij}x^k$. Since it is $R$-linear, it certainly preserves addition, so we just need to check that this map does indeed preserve multiplication. For this, it suffices to check on the basis.
$$\phi\newcommand\of[1]{\left({#1}\right)}\of{\of{x^kE_{ij}}\of{x^{k'}E_{i'j'}}}
=\phi\of{x^{k+k'}E_{ij}E_{i'j'}}=\phi\of{\delta_{ji'}x^{k+k'}E_{ij'}}=\delta_{ji'}E_{ij'}x^{k+k'},$$
and
$$\phi\of{x^kE_{ij}}\phi\of{x^{k'}E_{i'j'}}=\of{E_{ij}x^k}\of{E_{i'j'}x^{k'}}=E_{ij}E_{i'j'}x^{k+k'}=\delta_{ji'}E_{ij'}x^{k+k'}.$$
Thus $\phi$ preserves the multiplication as well.

If you think I've made an error, do let me know.